How to include dark and light theme in angular 18
I tried to implement a customer theme for angular and to have the ability to switch between dark and light mode. I tried many solutions but could not find the right way because angular is steadily changing the procedure and I didn't find the correct way for my version. Does anybody have a solution to use customer themes (with customer palettes) (so the theme (base colors) can be switched and also it reacts on changes regarding dark mode and light mode? I'm using Angular 18.2.11 with Angular Materials and a M3 customer theme.
theme-consumer.scss
// This file was generated by running 'ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme'.
// Proceed with caution if making changes to this file.

@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

// Note: Color palettes are generated from primary: #6e93ad, secondary: #fbe6ad, tertiary: #e28327, neutral: #d0effa
$_palettes: (
  primary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #001e2e,
    20: #06344a,
...
$_primary: map.merge(map.get($_palettes, primary), $_rest);
$_tertiary: map.merge(map.get($_palettes, tertiary), $_rest);

$light-theme: mat.define-theme((
  color: (
    theme-type: light,
    primary: $_primary,
    tertiary: $_tertiary,
  ),
));
$dark-theme: mat.define-theme((
  color: (
    theme-type: dark,
    primary: $_primary,
    tertiary: $_tertiary,
  ),
));

styles.scss
// Custom Theming for Angular Material
// For more information: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use './common.scss';
@use './theme-consumer.scss';
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat.core();

// Define the theme object.
$theme-consumer: mat.define-theme((
  color: (
    theme-type: light,
    primary: mat.$azure-palette,
    tertiary: mat.$blue-palette,
  ),
  density: (
    scale: 0,
  )
));

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
:root {
  @include mat.all-component-themes(theme-consumer.$light-theme);
}

.tertiary-radio {
  @include mat.radio-color(theme-consumer.$light-theme, $color-variant: tertiary);
}

// Comment out the line below if you want to use the pre-defined typography utility classes.
// For more information: https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#using-typography-styles-in-your-application.
@include mat.typography-hierarchy($theme-consumer);


As you can see I still have a fixed usage of the light theme. I tried to use
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { } to apply the dark theme but get errors because of duplicate definitions.
Any help is appreciated.
Best regards
Parascus

The problem could be solved by using mat.all-component-colours instead of mat.all-component-themes at the other positions.
